# Code generation in Visual Studio based on all files with a given extension

Tags: visual-studio, code-generation, t4, visual-studio-extensions

I have the following task: Make a visual editor in Visual Studio (not the core of today's question) which results in a text file, on a custom format. This file will then be used as input for code generation resulting in C# code. For this, I've been looking at:

- T4
- Visual Studio Extensions
- Visual Studio Project Templates
- Visual Studio Item Templates

I feel the solution is there somewhere, but I can't quite figure out how best to do it. As I see it, the main problem is somehow to automatically generate code for all files with a given extension. Does anyone know of any tutorials or descriptions on how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To automatically associate a code generator with all files of a given extension, you need to

- Create a Visual Studio package
- Implement a custom [IVsSingleFileGenerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssinglefilegenerator.aspx). The easiest option is to subclass the [BaseTemplatedCodeGenerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.texttemplating.vshost.basetemplatedcodegenerator.aspx) and override its GenerateCode method to supply your own T4 template as the "inputFileContent".
- Use the [ProvideCodeGeneratorAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.texttemplating.vshost.providecodegeneratorattribute.aspx) to register the generator.
- Use the [ProvideCodeGeneratorExtensionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.texttemplating.vshost.providecodegeneratorextensionattribute.aspx) to associate the generator with a file extension.
- Create a VSIX with your package and generator and have your users install it.